# A typedef in Java, for array types in particular

Tags: java

I'm building a graphing GIO and have the following interface:

```
public interface GraphModel
{
    public java.util.List<java.awt.geom.Point2D[]> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

But I find the fact that I have to use `java.awt.geom.Point2D[]` particularly loathsome as it will appear in a whole load of other interface functions. What I want to do is:

```
public interface GraphModel
{
    public class LayerType extends java.awt.geom.Point2D[]{};
    public java.util.List<LayerType> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

But this is not good since (i) you can't extend an array like this, and (ii) I question the wisdom of creating a dummy class just to model a language feature (the C++ `typedef`) that Java doesn't have.

Am I missing something here? Perhaps something with generics but then I effectively lose *all* type information.

Comment: what is problem in `List<LayerType[]>` with `public class LayerType extends java.awt.geom.Point2D{}`

Comment: *Could* do that but isn't creating a spoof class frowned upon? I'm scared my code reviewer will defenestrate me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesn't have `typedef`s. Although this won't be syntactically different, you can save some text-bloat by using `import`s (which most modern IDEs collapse so they don't irritate your eyes):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public interface GraphModel
{
    public List<Point2D[]> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

The only option you really have is to create a dummy class that wraps the array:

```
public class MyPoints {
    private Point2D[] myPoints;

    /* constructors, getters, setters, some logic you may have */
}

public interface GraphModel
{
    public List<MyPoints> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use import statements:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;

public interface GraphModel
{
    public List<Point2D[]> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

also prefer lists over arrays:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;

public interface GraphModel
{
    public List<List<Point2D>> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

And consider to use JavaFX instead of AWT/ Swing.

Answer (score 3):

[Favor Composition over Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

```
public class LayerType{

      private Point2D[] points;
      // setter & getter methods
};
```

And use

```
public interface GraphModel{
    public List<LayerType> getLayers();
    ...
}
```

**Note:** better use `List<Point2D>` instead of `Point2D[]` if the size of array is variable and not known in advance.